# PL/SQL: Is it possible to access the :NEW / :OLD with a variable holding the column name?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

first of all thanks for looking into my question. Well now to my problem. I was making a trigger listening for UPDATES writing in a logfile which columns had been changed and writing the new / old value of the column.

For example there is a table with these columns:

```
[ID]       [NAME]       [AGE]
1          Me           18
```

If I would now call:

```
UPDATE TABLE VALUES(1, 'Not Me', 19);
```

It was supposed to log:

```
[NAME], Me, Not Me
[AGE], 18, 19
```

First of all i wanted to get the column name dynamically so my trigger would work dynamically. That worked and i ended up having the column name in a variable like:

```
x.column_name
```

I know how to use :OLD / :NEW however I couldn't figure a way to get

```
e.g. :OLD.Id
:OLD => x.column_name                // where x.column_name would hold Id
```

I am not quite sure if this is simply not possible or I'm just missing something important on SQL.

Thanks in Advance for any answers ;)

Comment: I think that it is possible to implement your requirement using PL/SQL. Check out Zlatko Sirotic's post on this forum: https://community.oracle.com/message/370167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dynamically reference columns in a record (or a pseudo-record like `:new` or `:old`).  References to column names need to be static.

You could, however, dynamically generate the trigger (though this would mean that you would need to regenerate the trigger every time you add or remove columns).  There are a variety of approaches to this, here is [one AskTom example](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055) that uses a SQL*Plus script to generate the trigger dynamically.

Taking a step back, though, I'm always pretty dubious about storing audit data this way in the first place.  When every altered column is stored as a separate row in the audit table, the audit table gets quite large and running queries to see the prior state of a row requires joining the table to itself once for every column in the table.  That generally gets very slow very quickly.

Comment: In my experience "1 row per field" auditing is ugly, wastes space, and is difficult to interpret. What I've found works better is to have your audit table log the "after" values (e.g. all :NEW values), along with the date/time of the change (TIMESTAMP(9)) except on DELETE where you log the :OLD values. In this manner you can query the audit table, order by the change timestamp, and the changes from version to version are easy to see.

Comment: About performance and uglyness I was just playing around a little with a school exercise. So this two things weren't really imporant to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to log changes into a log table using [**the solution**](https://community.oracle.com/message/370167#370167) given on the OTN discussion forum.

To get it to work, I created the supporting tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE T_HISTORIE (hi_betreffende_tabelle varchar2(100),hi_betreffendes_feld varchar2(100),hi_wert_alt varchar2(100),hi_wert_neu varchar2(100));
CREATE TABLE T_HISTORIENSTEUERUNG (HS_TABELLE VARCHAR2(100),HS_FELD VARCHAR2(100));
```

`T_HISTORIENSTEUERUNG` is a table where you enter which tables and columns you want to log. For example, if you are interested in logging the changes to only the `NAME` column, then you would make an entry as follows:

```
INSERT INTO T_HISTORIENSTEUERUNG VALUES ('TABLE', 'NAME');
```

`T_HISTORIE` is the log table. It contains the table name, column name, the old value, and new value for every update that changes the value of a column, which has been configured to be logged (using the T_HISTORIENSTEUERUNG table). You could possibly add the time when the update was made, too. You would need to modify the PL/SQL package as well.

All subsequent updates to the TABLE would be logged.